# Full-text search with related tables in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, search, full-text-search, search-engine, postgresql-9.1

Task:
Implement full text search in multiple tables in PostgreSQL.

For example, a table of projects - projects:
There are two fields in which need to search: title and description.
Create an index on this table:

```
ALTER TABLE public.projects ADD COLUMN search_fts tsvector;
UPDATE public.projects SET search_fts =
to_tsvector(
    coalesce(title, '') ||' '||
    coalesce(description, '') || ' '
);
CREATE INDEX in_projects_idx ON public.projects
  USING gin (search_fts);
```

Now search is simple:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT p.id,
    p.title,
    ts_rank(
        p.search_fts,
        to_tsquery('word1 | word2')
    ) as rank
FROM
    projects p
WHERE
    p.search_fts @@ to_tsquery('word1 | word2')
ORDER BY rank DESC;
```

Sophisticate. Now we need to look at the table and project categories - project_categories.
Similar to create tsvector and for the table on the field name.
Search query now is:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT p.id,
    p.title,
    category.name as categoryName,
    ts_rank(
        (
            coalesce(p.search_fts, '') ||' '||
            coalesce(category.search_fts, '')
        ),
        to_tsquery('word1 | word2 | categoryName')
    ) as rank
FROM
    projects p
LEFT JOIN project_categories category
    ON p.category_id = category.category_id
WHERE
    (
        coalesce(p.search_fts, '') ||' '||
        coalesce(category.search_fts, '')
    ) @@ to_tsquery('word1 | word2 | categoryName')
ORDER BY rank DESC;
```

More sophisticate. Now the search has to work on dozens of tables related to projects as a one-to-many and many-to-many.

Number join's growing. Combine to a growing number of fields.

Actually the question the right way I'm going? How would you solve this problem?

I also think about the version with view.
For example, built on such a request:

```
(
  SELECT 
      p.id as project_id,
      p.search_fts
  FROM projects p
) UNION ALL (
  SELECT 
      p.id as project_id,
      category.search_fts
  FROM projects p
  JOIN project_categories category
      ON p.category_id = category.category_id
)
```

Finally, we obtain the overall index. By which to search.
But in the view have to combine a dozen requests for various communication options.
Interested in your views on this option.

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

- Use triggers on all the input tables to maintain a summary table that combines all the records of interest in text rows. This works OK for simple-ish cases like a `customer` that has 1 or more `phone` and one or more `address` entries, which you can put in the summary search table as `|customername|customerid|phone1|phone2|phone3|...|address1|address2|...` using simple concatenation and `string_agg` over joined tables. It scales poorly to deeply nested relationships, though, and can impose some locking and concurrency problems.
- Use an external search system like Apache Solr that's designed to solve complex search problems.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  
  
I also thought about the preparation of the overall index with triggers.  

But this option also does not look very comfortable, like all the options that I suggested.  
  
I think that tasks with a fairly simple search of the best solve without external search engines. I am quite satisfied with search tools that are in the postrgesql. Just wanted to find the best way of creating a general index.  
  
But, as it is a pity as all varinty not comfortable(

Comment: @ddmaster Yes, I agree that it'd be nice to have built-in support for multi-table full text search. There isn't, though, so your options are really to use an external tool or maintain a summary table with triggers. I'm not sure how multi-table full-text search could even work in Pg...